# App Engine - Query using a class member as parameter

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

I have a simple class, relevant details below:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class SimpleCategory implements Serializable{
... 
 public static enum type{
  Course,
  Category,
  Cuisine
 }

 @Persistent
 public type t;
...
}
```

I am attempting to query all SimpleCategory objects of the same type.

```
public SimpleCategory[] getCategories(SimpleCategory.type type) {
 PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

 try{
  Query q = pm.newQuery(SimpleCategory.class);
  q.setFilter("t == categoryType");
  q.declareParameters("SimpleCategory.type categoryType");
  List<SimpleCategory> cats = (List<SimpleCategory>) q.execute(type);
...
}
```

This results in a ClassNotResolvedException for SimpleCategory.type.  The google hits I've found so far recommended to:

- Use query.declareImports to specify the class i.e. q.declareImports("com.test.zach.SimpleCategory.type");
- Specify the fully qualified name of SimpleCategory in declareParameters

Neither of these suggestions has worked.  By removing .type and recompiling, I can verify that declareParameters **can** see SimpleCategory just fine, it simply cannot see the SimpleCategory.type, despite the fact that the remainder of the method has full visibility to it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something that has seemed to work for me is writing the query string using an implicit parameter and not using the declareParameters() method.

```
q.setFilter("t == :categoryType");
List<SimpleCategory> cats = (List<SimpleCategory>) q.execute(type)
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work well, I need to revisit the docs on  declareParameters(), I think I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You elided (`...`) whether `public static enum type` itself is declared `@PersistenceCapable`.  If it isn't, that might explain why the query parser isn't able to resolve a reference to the `type` class.

Comment: The enumeration is not @PersistenceCapable.  I thought that only classes and embedded classes were to be marked as @PersistenceCapable.  The 2 books I have on this subject have little to say on this topic.

Adding @PersistenceCapable to the enumeration has changed the error footprint slightly.  I will debug later when I've cooled down a bit.  Debugging app engine is the most willy nilly and frustrating set of libraries I have ever dealt with.

Comment: @Zach - Sorry, I don't know whether that is even the problem or whether enums need to be @PersistenceCapable.  I was simply suggesting another possibility to try.  I feel your pain.  I just got started with GAE JDO too and the rules and pitfalls are killing me too.